# Health Insurance coverage in UK

Tags: uk, canada, health, dual-nationality

I need current answer to this as many answers are years ago. I hold dual citizenship, British/Canadian. I receive a British pension. I lived for more than 20 years in UK. I am going to UK on holiday and want to know if I am covered by NHS while there.

Comment: Where are you visiting in the U.K.? In Scotland, if the pension you receive is a State Pension you will be able to get NHS treatment for conditions that develop while you are in the U.K, https://www.nhsinform.scot/media/1141/health-care-for-uk-pensioners-visiting-scotland-v6-2016-198.pdf I believe the same applies elsewhere in the U.K. but haven’t been able to locate a definitive document - each Health Trust seems to publish its own

Comment: @rhialto No, the section on the rights of those receiving a State Pension and living abroad is on page 1.

Comment: What do you mean ‘on page 1’ - pls spell it all out - I am a novice.

Comment: Page 1 of the link in my earlier comment

Answer (score 2):

Only treatment in Accident&Emergency departments and GP surgeries is free for all https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-overseas-visitors-hospital-charging-regulations/summary-of-changes-made-to-the-way-the-nhs-charges-overseas-visitors-for-nhs-hospital-care  In England, free NHS hospital treatment is provided on the basis of someone being ‘ordinarily resident’. https://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/AboutNHSservices/uk-visitors/Pages/access-services-in-England.aspx  If you are visiting England from a non-EEA country, you need to ensure you are covered for healthcare through personal medical insurance for the duration of your visit, even if you are a former UK resident. 
If you need NHS treatment and have not arranged insurance, you will be charged at 150% of the standard NHS rate, unless an exemption category applies to either you or the treatment. If you are coming for more than six months, you may need to pay the immigration health surcharge.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that even if you do qualify for NHS care it certainly won’t repatriate you, so you may find yourself ill or injured in the UK facing a massive bill for medically appropriate transport to get back to Canada. You need travel insurance.